# Cookies not sent with AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to send a cross domain AJAX request, but I can't seem to get the authentication cookie to tag along. The request is being sent from www.site.com/path to api.site.com/other/path. The cookie's details include:

Domain               : .site.com
Path                 : /
Send for             : Any kind of connection
Accessible to script : Yes

And here's the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'http://api.site.com/path',
    contentType : "application/json",
    xhrFields   : {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain : true,
    beforeSend  : function(xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true
    },
    data        : JSON.stringify({
        'user_id' : 'id'
    }),
    success     : function() {
        alert('success');
    },
    error       : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

I control both the creation and the consumption of the cookie. Obviously, some of the details above are redundant, but I've sort of been trying everything I can come with without success. I'd love to take the cookie back to HttpOnly if possible. I really thought I could solve this one, but I'm obviously missing something. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Write a small proxy which resides on domain-b and forwards your requests to domain-a. Your browser will allow you to call the proxy because it's on the same server as the calling script.
2. This proxy then can be configured by you to accept a cookie name and value parameter which it can send to domain-a. But for this to work you need to know the cookie's name and value your server on domain-a wants for authentication.
3. If you're fetching JSON objects try to use a JSONP request instead. jQuery supports these. But you need to alter your service on domain-a so that it returns valid JSONP responds.

Tell me if it works. If not, I'll look for yet another solution.